# How to organize large javascript game projects?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a flash developer and I've recently been looking into HTML5 game development using canvas and javascript. I have a couple of books and several tutorials and I still haven't found a decent way to organize the files.

In some examples all the code is in one single game.js, other times it's in several external js files and all referenced in the html script tags one after the other (looks like a mess once you have 10 files or more).

So what's the best practice to organize large projects?

Comment: Use separate files for development and minify and combine for production